# Call to a member function setId() on boolean issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1

I receiving this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in ...

This is how my block is declared:

```
    <blocks>
        <emailtester>
            <class>Yireo_EmailTester_Block</class>
        </emailtester>
    </blocks>
```

This is my block from where the error occurs:

```
 class Yireo_EmailTester_Block_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
 {
...

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setChild('check', $this->getCheckBlock());
        $rt = parent::_toHtml();
        return $rt;
    }


    protected function getCheckBlock()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('emailtester/form_check')->setId('check');
     //   return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('emailtester/form_check')->setId('check');
    }
```

Whatever string I type instead of **emailtester/form_check** I still get this error message. Any idea what could cause this issue? thank you in advance for any idea

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code Magento tries to render the block by calling `toHtml()` on the block, which is a standard function for rendering Blocks in Magento. But your block isn't called properly, so it's `boolean false` which obviously does not have a method `toHtml`

Comment: This is block: emailtester/form_check. See my block declaration in the xml. I have the folder Form and my file Check.php . I put in the constructor from Check.php and echo 1; exit(). I didn't get it. I don't know what else should i check. thx :)

Comment: Have you added your block in the layout?

Comment: I updated my post, could you pleas check it ? txh